# Custom view onDraw() not refreshing on Oreo

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-8.0-oreo

I custom a view in an dialog, a loading animation circle
the code may like below:

```
rotateValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 360).setDuration(1000);
rotateValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            startPosition = integer;
            postInvalidate();
        }
    });

private void drawProgressCircle(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(progressColor);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, startPosition, percentage * 360, false, paint);
}
```

However, the animate just showed the first frame then stuck.
This case just happened on the devices with Android O

Comment: Please, clarify how do you start the animator and how is `drawProgressCircle` called.

Comment: The case just happened on device with android O, which means the animator and the draw works fine on the others